# Minimize travelling cost for N people visiting a subset of M cities

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem that was asked in an interview.

Given are names of `N` travellers, `M` cities and costs of travelling per-person between cities `M`<sub>i</sub> and `M`<sub>j</sub> as `C`<sub>ij</sub>. Each traveller `N`<sub>i</sub> has to visit a given subset `S`<sub>i</sub> of the `M` places.  And a number `X`.

- All travellers start their journey from a common city.
- They can visit a city that is not in their list of cities to be visited.
- A traveller can stay in a city for an arbitrary amount of time.
- They are required to return to the origin city.
- All cities are connected.
- One can visit same city multiple times.
- `X < min( {C} )`

**Problem :**  If `T` number of travellers make a journey together, then they'd save `(T-1)*X` amount on the total cost of travel between a pair of cities. We need to determine the order of visit for each traveller so as to minimize the overall cost of travel by all travellers.

**Sample test case :**

**Inputs:**

```
N = 4       M = 4
travellers[N] = { "person_one", "person_two", "person_three", "person_four" }
cities[M]     = { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
costs = {
          A <--> B = 100
          A <--> C = 120
          A <--> D = 50
          B <--> C = 20
          B <--> D = 20
          C <--> D = 20
        }

target_cities = {
                  person_one   = { "A", "B" }
                  person_two   = { "A", "B", "C", "D" }
                  person_three = { "A", "C", "D" }
                  person_four  = { "A", "D" }
                }

X = 10
Assuming they all start from city A.
```

**Output :**

```
person_one   : A -> D ------> B -> D -> A // the extra spacing is for convenience in
person_two   : A -> D -> C -> B -> D -> A // understanding, original output can have
person_three : A -> D -> C ------> D -> A // uniform spaces
person_four  : A -> D ----------------> A
```

**Explaination :**

```
- they save 3*10 by travelling to D together
- person two and three save 1*10 from D -> C.
- person one and two travel back to D from B to save 3*10 
  travelling from D -> A.
```

So far I haven't been able to figure out any way to solve this problem. I'd like to know the approach that I can take.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample input and output as well, for the above question ?

Comment: Yes, I'll make a test case and edit the question.

Comment: sure sounds good :)

Comment: Isn't this a travelling salesman problem on steroids?

Comment: That seems very tough for an interview.

Comment: I agree that seems like really really tough question for interview.

Comment: I agree with n.m. that this is just TSP on steroids. Which makes it unanswerable in an interview. So IMO the goal of the question was to see how you react to an impossible task. Do you recognize it as impossible? Can you explain a variety of approaches, along with their advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Can a traveler visit a city more than once?

Comment: I have added the sample test case.

Comment: @Ari yes, they are allowed to do so

Comment: @user3386109 I did try to convey that it was unanswerable but as the interviewer insisted on giving a solution, I said "we'll brute-force it". I really couldn't think of anything better. I am fresh out of college and this question was beyond my capability.

Comment: Having done the example by hand, I think the solution is to solve TSP separately for each person. And then maximize the discounts by adding delays to the shorter itineraries (to align travel dates). Using this technique, the answer to the example is `one="AD.BDA"` `two="ADCBDA"` `three="ADC.DA"` `four="AD...A"` where a `.` represents a delay used to align travel dates. This solution gives a total cost of 460, compared to the 620 of the solution in the question. This is not perfect (because some itineraries may be rearranged without changing the TSP cost) but it's a good approximation.

Comment: @user3386109 this is actually covered by X < min { Cost } so no need for extra constraint there.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you  for the hint and correction in the output. Please edit the output in the question if you'd like to or shall I do it?

Comment: @np_complete Thanks for the offer. I think it's best if you manage the question.

Comment: @np_complete Just curious, if you can say it. What company asked this question?

Comment: @Dici it was Nissan digital